# Unity episode does not end even if the goal or wall is touched

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zPFU30tbyKs&t=1676s tutorial on ML agents. I didn't change almost anything from the code except for the OnEpisodeBegin function where I replaced Vector3.zero; with the starting position of my agent.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.MLAgents;
using Unity.MLAgents.Actuators;
using Unity.MLAgents.Sensors;

public class MoveAgent : Agent
{
    [SerializeField] 
    private Transform targetTransform;

    public override void OnEpisodeBegin(){
        transform.position = new Vector3(42.59956f, 18.9153f, 144.7489f);
    }

    public override void CollectObservations(VectorSensor sensor){
        sensor.AddObservation(transform.position);
        sensor.AddObservation(targetTransform.position);
    }

    public override void OnActionReceived(ActionBuffers actions){
        float moveX = actions.ContinuousActions[0];
        float moveZ = actions.ContinuousActions[1];

        float moveSpeed = 2f;

        transform.localPosition += new Vector3(moveX, 0, moveZ) * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
    }
    public override void Heuristic(in ActionBuffers actionsOut){
        ActionSegment<float> continuousActions = actionsOut.ContinuousActions;
        continuousActions[0] = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        continuousActions[1] = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
        if (other.TryGetComponent<Goal>(out Goal goal)){
            SetReward(+1f);
            EndEpisode();
        }

        if (other.TryGetComponent<Wall>(out Wall wall)){
            SetReward(-1f);
            EndEpisode();
        }
    }
}
`

What could the problem be?
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug? Is the trigger getting called at all? Is there a `Wall` component ..?

Comment: Yes, there is a wall component. I will try to debug (didn't think about doing this) and see what the problem is thank you.